# Login Flow if user is going to order stuff

Tags: app, android

Given the user has to fill in contact telephone number and address.

If the new customer is going to make an order, the customer has to ask the user to login. After successful login, should the user go back to order page?

Answer (score 1):

I worked in e-commerce so I have some experience. It really depends on the kind of shop, because every checkout is different.

1. you could ask the user to sign up after leaving the shopping cart to the checkout and make that a seperate screen. After that you proceed to the payment details in the checkout.
2. you could have a section in your checkout where the user has to fill in his email & 2x password and probably like a checkbox to agree with terms and conditions. Because that's the most relevant info to create an account.
3. you could give the user the option to sign up or continue as a guest, user continues as guest. then after the order is done you give the option to sign up, and the customer also receives an email to signup, with some benefits as to why that is worth it.